# How to cast one parameter in function as void pointer parameter to an integer

Tags: c, pointers

I am having this function fun, where I am passing the nums structure as a parameter. The thing is that I need to convert this field into an integer inside the function. 
How can I do this without changing the way I am passing the structure in the function?

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
struct node{
    char *str;
    struct node *next;
};

struct numbers{
    struct node *head;
    int *new_a;
};

void *fun(void *args);

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
        int *new_a, num_a;
        struct node *head=NULL;

        struct numbers *args = (struct numbers *)malloc(sizeof(struct numbers));

        num_a = returnNum();

        pthread_t pthread;
        new_a = malloc(1);
        *new_a = num_a;
        args->new_a=new_a;

        if( pthread_create( &pthread , NULL , (void *) &fun , (void *) &args) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }

}

void *fun(void *args){

    //void *num_a = (int *) args->new_a;
    //int num_a = *(int*)(args->new_a);
    struct numbers *temp_str = (struct numbers *) (*args);
    int num_a = (int) *(args->new_a);
    ...
}
```

Also, how can I do the casting for the head node?
Can anyone please advice?

Comment: Keeping an pointer to integer in the structure rather than storing the integer directly in the structure seems unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a `struct numbers *` is being passed to `fun`, you need to assign the parameter to a variable of this type.  Then you can use the struct.

```
void *fun(void *arg){
    struct numbers *temp_str = arg;   // no need to cast from void *
    int num_a =  temp_str->new_a;
    ...
}
```

There's also a problem with how you populate the struct:

```
    int *new_a, num_a;
    ...
    new_a = malloc(1);
    *new_a = num_a;
    args->new_a=new_a;
```

You're not allocating enough space for `new_a`.  You only allocate 1 byte, but an `int` on most systems is 4 bytes.  When you subsequently read and write from this memory location, you read/write past the end of the memory that was allocated.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case manifests as a crash..

You can fix this by allocating the proper amount of space:

```
new_a = malloc(sizeof(*new_a));
```

However, you don't need to use dynamic memory allocation for this field at all.  Just declare `new_a` as `int` and write to it directly:

```
struct numbers{
    struct node *head;
    int new_a;
};

...

args->new_a = returnNum();
```

You also don't need to take the address of `args`.  It's a pointer, so pass it to `pthread_create` directly:

```
if( pthread_create( &pthread , NULL , fun , args) < 0)
```

Comment: hi@dbush, but i need to do the casting to int :)

Comment: @user9091498 Not if you have a valid pointer to the struct.  Then you can do `int number = *my_nums->new_a;`

Comment: @user9091498 Define "doesn't work", and be **specific**.  Also, update your question to show how `fun` is called and how the parameter is populated.

Comment: it gives errors during compile.. i am actually trying to work with threads, so while calling the create thread function, it calls function fun, so i need to send as parameters one integer and the pointer to the head of my list. So the only way i found that is working, is to put them in a struct. So i need to pass my struct as void and then do the cast inside fun.

Comment: @user9091498 Don't describe the code, **show** the code.  Describing code is saying "this is basically what my code does".  The problem is computers don't do "basically" what you tell them.  They do **exactly** what you tell them.  So tell us **exactly** what you're telling the computer to do, i.e. show your code as an update to your question.

Comment: @user9091498 This is much more clear now.  This is why a [mcve] is important.  See my edit.

Comment: `The problem is computers don't do "basically" what you tell them. They do exactly what you tell them` I need to remember this. You made my Day. Thank you.

Comment: @dbush really appreciate your help! seems to be ok now, thanks

Comment: @user9091498 Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.